# Mock internal class instantiations in method

Tags: phpunit

I have the following code in a `Ships::class` that I'm trying to right a test for.

```php
public function addShip($data, $columns = [])
{
    $columns = $columns ? $columns : $this->defaultColumns;
    $bridgeOfficers = new BridgeOfficers(['pdo' => $this->pdo]);
    $abilities = new Abilities(['pdo' => $this->pdo]);
    $traits = new Traits(['pdo' => $this->pdo]);
    $prices = new Prices(['pdo' => $this->pdo]);

    //...
}
```

Is there a way to mock these classes or do I need to refactor my code to make them more testable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mock these classes, technically not possible. If something cannot be mocked or can only be mocked with a very high effort, it is always an indication that something is wrong with the software architecture. Therefore, you should refactor your code.

It depends on the requirements I would do it like this. You can then mock BridgeOfficers, Abilities, Traits and Prices for tests.

If it's only about `$this->pdo`, I would still initialise all classes via the constructor, because then you have more flexibility.

```php
class Ship
{
    private BridgeOfficers $bridgeOfficers;
    private Abilities $abilities;
    private Traits $traits;
    private Prices $prices;


    public function __construct(BridgeOfficers $bridgeOfficers, Abilities $abilities, Traits $traits, Prices $prices)
    {
        $this->bridgeOfficers = $bridgeOfficers;
        $this->abilities = $abilities;
        $this->traits = $traits;
        $this->prices = $prices;
    }


    public function addShip($data, $columns = [])
    {
        $columns = $columns ? $columns : $this->defaultColumns;
        $bridgeOfficers = $this->bridgeOfficers;
        $abilities = $this->abilities;
        $traits = $this->traits;
        $prices = $this->prices;
    }

}

$ship = new Ship(
    new BridgeOfficers(['pdo' => $this->pdo]),
    new Abilities(['pdo' => $this->pdo]),
    new Traits(['pdo' => $this->pdo]),
    new Prices(['pdo' => $this->pdo])
);
$ship->addShip('...');
```

Comment: Thanks! I can see this class growing quite a lot. Are there any other viable alternatives to deal with this other than dependency injection? I'm new to learning these design patterns.

Comment: The choice of design pattern depends on the requirements. Therefore, I cannot really answer your questions. In PHP, the only way to integrate a service/class into another service/class is to do so. You could also use setters, but then you have to check that the services are set. If you use Symfony or Laravel you have more options: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html or https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container